# Problemas ao enviar dados via _GET

Tags: php

Estou enfrentando um problema básico da linguagem (ao meu ver), e não estou conseguindo resolver.
Tenho um formulário e estou pegando o dado do formulário via Jquery e jogando para um arquivo para montar um PDF. Porém esses dados estão sendo enviados via $_GET.

Porém um dos campos é texto, e percebi uma situação onde se o usuário colocar o caracter '&', o texto se perde, por conta da forma de envio desse dado.

Eu sei que poderia resolver enviando os dados via POST, porém eu não posso submeter o formulário.

Comment: Você esta montando a URL na mão ao submeter... normalmente o conteúdo do campo de texto é codificado de forma apropriada, mesmo que contenha o caractere `&`?

Comment: O valor do `&` é codificado como `%26` pelo navegador.

Comment: Insira o código que você para chamar o formulário e também do PDF.

Comment: Como você ta usando Jquery, faça pelo serialize(), que a mesma vai propor automáticamente a conversão do **&** para **%26**

Comment: Onde o usuário passa o parâmetro data do jquery use o $("#idform").serialize();

Answer (score 3):

Se você está usando jquery para enviar o formulario tente envia-lo dessa forma:

```
$('form').serialize();
```

Comment: não funciona, mesmo assim, existe a divisão das informações.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma função no PHP que codifica os caracteres especias nas URL's, que se chama [urlencode](http://br.php.net/url_encode). E pra decodificar utiliza-se o [urldecode](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: mas eu não estou usando o PHP para gerar a URL, estou criando o link na mão, via Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Se você esta gerando a url via jquery, você pode usar `encodeURIComponent` para pegar os valores digitados nos campos, ele codifica os caracteres especiais.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

[Exemplo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4k5sf/)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode codificar o texto em [Base64](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

## PHP

No PHP você pode usar as funções `php_encode()` e `php_decode()` para codificar e decodificar, respectivamente.

[Veja a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-decode.php).

## Javascript

Já no Javascript existem as funções `btoa()` e `atob()`, que codificam e decodificam, respectivamente.

[Veja a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

[Veja um exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/LSsHe/).

---

A ideia é tu codificar via Javascript para enviar via GET para o servidor; e no servidor tu decodifica antes de salvar no banco (ou oque quer que tu faça com esse dado).